# Restrict log file size

Tags: io-redirection

I'm trying to limit the number of lines in my log file using:

```
php $PWD/private_html/run_worker.php | head -n 20000 >> $PWD/private_html/data/logfile.txt 2>&1 &
```

If I run the command without the "| head -n 20000", my output is being redirected.  However, when I include the limiting code, nothing gets written to the log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's probably a better tool for this than `head`, but what happens when you turn off buffering with e.g. `stdbuf` ?

Comment: Putting `2>&1` after the `head` is unlikely to be useful. Did you mean to write a construct formed like `php ... 2>&1 | head ... >> logfile`?

Comment: @roaima Still no results

Comment: @thrig Sorry for being such a noob, but can you please show me the stdbuf syntax in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suffering from Buffering

First off, there may be buffering; by default output to not-terminal-not-standard-error is block buffered (per [setvbuf(3)](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man3/setvbuf.3)) so one should not expect to see any logs until after a buffer is filled (or not at all when something crashes or eats a fatal signal). This is best tested with two terminals, one to run the commands, and the other to `tail -f` the output file:

```
# terminal watcher (how do the log lines appear in the logfile?)
rm logf; touch logf; tail -f logf

# terminal test commands (feed logfile)
php -r 'while(1){echo "logline\n";sleep(1);}' >> logf
...
^C
perl -E 'while(1){say "logline";sleep 1}' >> logf
...
^C
```

From this it appears (at least on my system) that PHP does not block buffer standard out, a departure from the default; however, `head` does buffer, and `stdbuf` does not help, as the log lines all appear in a clump:

```
php -r 'while(1){echo "logline\n";sleep(1);}' | head -7 >> logf
php -r 'while(1){echo "logline\n";sleep(1);}' | stdbuf -o 0 -- head -7 >> logf
```

So `head` is probably not the right tool for this task. (As a side-note, various applications will buffer internally, so whatever horrible things `stdbuf` is doing may not help:

```
stdbuf -o 0 perl -E 'while(1){say "logline";sleep 1}' >> logf
perl -E 'STDOUT->autoflush;while(1){say "logline";sleep 1}' >> logf
```

If at all possible, set the appropriate buffering in the application itself.)

## As to the Logs

A hard limit on log lines would require something that consumes N lines, but then stays open (or does the application then get killed, or...?):

```
php -r 'while(1){echo "logline\n";sleep(1);}' 2>&1 \
| perl -ne 'BEGIN{STDOUT->autoflush; $N=7 } if($N>0){print;$N--}' >> logf
```

Or this could be done internally with PHP, assuming all the logs can be routed through a function to handle this task, or a logging module or framework. Otherwise, there are [a bunch of tools that log rotate standard out](https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout), with varying levels of options and learning curves involved, though these appear to lack "N lines" and instead set caps based on size.